# NLTK Grammar with enumeration semantics

Tags: python, nltk, grammar, enumeration, semantics

**Info and code**

Let Grammar.cfg be the file for my grammar (commented for info):

```
// Rules
S[SEM = <app(?vp, ?suj)>] -> GN[SEM = ?suj] VP[SEM = ?vp] // This is the important line really.
GN[SEM = ?suj] -> NP[SEM = ?suj]
VP[SEM = ?v] -> V[SEM = ?v]
NP[SEM = ?n] -> Nprop[SEM = ?n]

// Words
Nprop[SEM = <john>] -> 'john'
V[SEM = <\x.eat (x)>] -> 'eats'
```

And the python file to parse stuff with it:

```
import nltk
from nltk import *

with open ("Grammar.cfg", "r") as myfile:
    grammarText = myfile.read()

grammar = grammar.FeatureGrammar.fromstring(grammarText)
parser = nltk.ChartParser(grammar)
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize("John eats.".lower())

stemmedTokens = []
for token in tokens:
    stemmedTokens.append(stemmer.stem(token))

parser = parse.FeatureEarleyChartParser(grammar)
trees = parser.parse(tokens)
for tree in trees:
    print(tree)
    nltk.draw.tree.draw_trees(tree)
    print(tree.label()['SEM'])
```

If I try that, it would result in `eat (john)`.

**Problem**

How would I proceed if I wanted to support (and extract the semantics of) enumerations in my sentences such as:

> John, Bob and Sam eat.

Considering all the words would be present in the grammar.
I'm looking for something kind of like:

`GN[SEM = <app(?s1,?s2,...,?sn)>] -> NP[SEM = ?s1] NP[SEM = ?s2] ... NP[SEM = ?sn]`

to result in parsing similar to:

`eat (list(john, bob, sam))` or `went (bob, list(canada, usa, mexico, france))`

I know the successive `NP[SEM = ?s]` groups are to be handled with recursive patterns, this is just to show what I'm trying to achieve.